# Trouble with Form.DialogResult

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog, dialogresult

```
private void mnuCustomerAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomerForm frmCust = new CustomerForm("Add A New Customer");

        int index = lstCustomers.SelectedIndex;
        if (index != -1)
            frmCust.CustomerData = new Customer(customerMngr.GetCustomer(index).ContactData);


        MessageBox.Show("dev1");
        DialogResult dr = frmCust.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("dev2");
            if (frmCust.ReadInput())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("dev3");
                customerMngr.AddCustomer(frmCust.CustomerData);
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Please supply all necessary fields with the correct information");
        }
        UpdateCustomerList();

    }
```

Don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, I want to execute the conditional statements if the user hits OK in the Form that appears at `frmCust.ShowDialog()`.
At the moment I can only get to "dev1".

Comment: Are you even setting the `DialogResult` in the dialog?

Comment: Please give this post an actual question / title. Simply putting in code does not help anyone understand the issue at a glance.

Comment: MSDN is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx

Comment: I've fixed the question!
Thanks for the link to MSDN, unfortunately I find it hard to use so I turn to stackoverflow instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps your dialog isn't setting the dialog result.  Make sure your OK and Cancel buttons have their `DialogResult` properties set to what you expect.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it was the most straight forward solution, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Be sure correctly assign [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx) property of the `Form` before it closed. 
So it will be returned like a return value of `ShowDilaog()` call.

There is another option too, is use [AcceptButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton.aspx) and [CancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton.aspx), in order to handle corresponding `Enter` and `Cancel` keypress.

Answer (score 1):

Place a Breakpoint (F9) on the line:

```
if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
```

When the dialog closes you will have chance to examine what `dr` is set to.

To get the Dialog to return DialogResult.OK you can either set it in the OK button of the Dialog:

```
void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    Close();
}
```

Or you can do the option in Tigran's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8979695/383710).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll examine the faulty variable next time more closely.